# FFmpeg does unnecessary muxing

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, codec, aac, video-conversion

I am writing a script that takes videofiles such as MKV or AVI and changes them to MP4, and then prepares them from web streaming. I want my output to use H.264 and AAC codecs.

So far my command looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 output.mp4
```

However, when the codec already is h.264 it still muxes it, it says: (h264 -> libx264).

If I replace '-vcodec h264' with '-vcodec copy' it goes a lot faster when the codec is H.264 but of course won't change the codec if there is a different codec in the input file.

Is there a way for FFmpeg to recognize that the codec is almost the same, and thus not muxing the videostream, but still changing video codec if the source isn't H.264?

Comment: You will have to analyze the video before you pass it to ffmpeg. if already h264 then mux, if not transcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. FFmpeg can only copy bitstreams *or* re-encode. It can't guess if you want to keep a certain codec. You'll have to parse the file info and then decide whether you want to copy or not.

Some examples of how to do that are listed here: [MKV to MP4 transcoding script issues](https://superuser.com/questions/275193/mkv-to-mp4-transcoding-script-issues/544214#544214)

Basically, you could do this (shameless plug from @evilsoup there):

```
ffprobe input.mkv 2>&1 | sed -n '/Video:/s/.*: \([a-zA-Z0-9]*\).*/\1/p' | sed 1q'
```

This would output `h264` for an H.264 video stream.

<sub>Minor tip: Try getting used to specifying the exact encoder you want. `h264` isn't really an encoder for FFmpeg – it defaults to `libx264`. So rather use `-c:v libx264`.</sub>
<sub>One more thing: `aac` is the built-in AAC encoder from FFmpeg. Third party encoders like `libfdk_aac` or `libfaac` offer a VBR encoding mode and generally better quality than `aac`.</sub>

Comment: I was afraid I would have to do a check. But thanks a lot for the tips!!